# what does it mean?? TypeError: human.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'sex', 'height', and 'weight'

Tags: python, typeerror

```py
import datetime

class human:
    def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth, sex, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth
        self.sex = sex
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        


    def BMI(self):
        bmi = self.weight / self.height**2
        return bmi
    


    def get_life_expectency(self):
        if self.sex == 'male':
            life_expectency = 73
        else:
            life_expectency = 79
        return life_expectency

    @classmethod
    def age_calculation(cls, name, year_of_birth, sex, height, weight):
        return cls(name, datetime.datetime.now().year - year_of_birth)

        
            
h1 = human.age_calculation('masoud', 1997, 'man', 1.78, 86)
```

I expected the codes to return the age in years and this happened:

```
TypeError: human.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'sex', 'height', and 'weight'
```

Comment: Two things: (1) rename that class to `Human`, as per the Python conventions. And (2), fix `age_calculation` because you're calling the class constructor with 2 arguments, so just like the error explicitly tells you: you're missing 3 arguments in your constructor call. And then really, (3) just use `h1 = Human(.......)`, why did you try to write a factory class method? (And why does it not even have the right name? It's not calculating anything, it's creating a class instance. Name your functions after what they do, and your variables after what they represent)

Comment: @h0r53 you don't need an _instance_ to call _class_ methods.

Comment: In your age_calculation method you only pass 2 arguments to the constructor. It requires 5 values

Answer (score 0):

By returning `cls(...)` you are creating an instance of that class. What you wanted to do was return `datetime.datetime.now().year - year_of_birth`

Comment: More importantly, `age_calculation` should be a regular instance method that uses `self.year_of_birth` rather than taking the year of birth as an argument.

Comment: thank you. I was just practicing the OOP with online courses :) I wasn't doing anything serious but thank you you were really helpful.